# difference between server appium and server inside appium studio

Tags: appium, appium-ios, appium-android

Hello i found one interesting difference between server which use appium studio and usual appium

```
@iOSFindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='LATabController_AccountButton']")
```

fist row working only for server inside of appium studio but doesn't work usual appium with error

```
@iOSFindBy(id = "LATabController_AccountButton")
```

second work for usual appium and for appium studio

my goal and question:
How  i can use first example of code for usual appium?
or where i can find server which use appium studio?
or any other way to use this code with out appium studio

Answer (score 0):

The first example is not good code. Even if that's supported, there's absolutely no reason to use it.

The second example is the correct way to do what you're trying to do. Regardless of support, you should be using this in Appium Studio and standard Appium.